# Firebase storage - resize image extension

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase-storage, firebase-extensions

i wanted to **resize my images**, so i installed this resize image extension.

Problem is it only resize image if i upload it on firebase website. Problem is if i upload it through **nodejs** or **flutter**, it does not resize..

Do i need to set some metadata or what? Does it only work for firebase website? Or is it possible to somehow trigger extension?

````
_reference.putData(
        await pickedImage.readAsBytes(),
        SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpg'),
      ); ```
````

Comment: The image resizer extension should trigger for all uploaded images. Does the uploaded image show up in you Cloud Storage bucket (e.g. in the Firebase console)?

Comment: I found the problem, i cant use "image/jpg" because its not supported by extension.